# No funciona suma decimal

Tags: javascript

Hola buenas tengo un problema no consigo realizar una suma decimal, recogo dos variables de los contenidos de dos span, los tranformo a Float y se suman pero no con decimales aquí os dejo el código:

```
var Precio = document.getElementById("Precio" + valor).innerText;
var PrecioCaja = document.getElementById("PrecioCaja" + valor).innerText;

    var Precio2 = parseFloat(Precio);
    var PrecioCaja = parseFloat(PrecioCaja);

    Precio2 = (Precio2) + (PrecioCaja);
    Precio2 = Precio2;
    document.getElementById("Precio"+ valor).innerHTML=Precio2;
```

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Comment: Agrega tu html, veo que tratar de obtener el elemento dinámicamente con su valor, eso es correcto?, para más exactitud y comprensión del problema sube html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con esto

```
let precio = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#precio').innerText);
            let precio_caja = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#precio_caja').innerText);
            let precio_final = precio+precio_caja;
            console.log(precio_final);
```

Comment: Lo siento amigo de esta manera no me suma en decimal. De la manera que tu me propones las variables no se guardan en decimal no se por que...

Comment: Disculpa error mio en la base de datos, todo arreglado gracias por la ayuda